# Slider showing wrong values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uislider

Hello : Im developping an application and I'd like to display the value of a UISlider as the user moove it along the bar.

I created an `IBOutlet` linked in Interface Builder to an `UILabel` and a `IBAction` linked in Interface Builder to the slider. They are declared as following in the `Information.h` :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *DispTemp;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *SetTemperature;

-(IBAction) DisplayTemp:(id) sender;
```

I didnt forget the `@synthesize DispTemp;` and `@synthesize SetTemperature;` in the `Information.m` .I'm using this code for the `IBAction` :

```
-(IBAction) DisplayTemp:(id) sender{
    self.DispTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.SetTemperature.value];
}
```

Obviously the Link with interface builder is working because as i moove the slider the value changes. However i set the range from -10 to 30 with a 0,5 step but the value that are shown moove from -a few millions to +a few million and come back regularly to 0. I dont know what is going on, any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a wrong format specifier (`%d` is for `int`). The `value` property of sliders has type `float`:

```
self.DispTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.SetTemperature.value];
```

Comment: Oh my gosh ! Thanks a lot i was becoming crazy :D